# React Native Navigation Bar Left Button

Tags: react-native

how do I combined that icon with a strings in react native navbar leftButton

Here's my code:

```
<NavigationBar
      tintColor={"#9b2b25"}
      leftButton={{
      title: {<Icon name="chevron-left" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />Back},
      handler:  () => this.props.navigator.pop()
 } />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Navigator and routeMapper, just add something like this to the route mapper:

```
NavigationBarRouteMapper =
  LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return if index == 0 && !route.leftTitle && !route.leftButton
    previousRoute = navState.routeStack[index - 1]
    backButton = route.leftButton || previousRoute && <Icon style={styles.backChevron} name='chevron-left' size=22 />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => (try route.leftButtonAction()) || navigator.pop()}>
      <View style={[styles.buttons, styles.leftButtonHolder]}>
        {backButton}
        <Text style={[textElements.mediumText, styles.navBarText, NavigationBarRouteMapper.backTextStyle(backButton)]}>
          {route.leftTitle || (try previousRoute.title)}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   }
```

This way if there was an object in the previous route stack, you will get the back-chevron and text.